# I need to pivot some data in SQL multiple date columns for each combination

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My problem is I want each GNetPre to be a column and have the Name_Eff_Date and Name_Term_Date to be a seperate columns to the right of the GNetPre column with it's GAgreeID under with the dates that correspond.  The solution works perfect except the layout is messing looking in the results based on how I have a mock-up of it.

I've tried this->https://anthonysmoak.com/2018/08/05/how-to-dynamically-pivot-data-in-sql-server/

Sample Data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLfCH.png)
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TBL_TEMP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##TBL_TEMP

```
--This parameter will hold the dynamically created SQL script
DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--This parameter will hold the Pivoted Column values
DECLARE   @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT   @PivotColumns= COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME([GroupNetworkPrefix]) 
FROM #ALLGroup

/* UNCOMMENT TO SEE THE NEW COLUMN NAMES THAT WILL BE CREATED */
--SELECT   @PivotColumns

--Create the dynamic query with all the values for
--pivot column at runtime
--LIST ALL FILEDS EXCEPT PIVOT COLUMN

SET   @SQLQuery =
   N'SELECT GroupID,
Name,
GovtID,
GTermDate,
' +   @PivotColumns + ',
Name_Eff_Date,
Name_Term_Date
   INTO ##TBL_TEMP
   FROM #ALLGroup

   PIVOT( MAX([GAgreeID])
      FOR [GNetPre] IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS Q'

/* UNCOMMENT TO SEE THE DYNAMICALLY CREATED SQL STATEMENT */
--SELECT   @SQLQuery
--Execute dynamic query
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery

/* VIEW PIVOTED TABLE RESULTS */
Select * from ##TBL_TEMP
```

Expected (or wanted) results:

```
+------------+-------+--------+------------+-----+---------------+----------------+-----+---------------+----------------+-----+---------------+----------------+
|  GroupID   | Name  | GovtID | GTermDate  | AB  | Name_Eff_Date | Name_Term_Date | CD  | Name_Eff_Date | Name_Term_Date | MM  | Name_Eff_Date | Name_Term_Date |
+------------+-------+--------+------------+-----+---------------+----------------+-----+---------------+----------------+-----+---------------+----------------+
| 12345 | James |  13131 | 12/31/9999 | NM1 | 2017-10-01    | 9999-12-31     | NM1 | 2017-10-01    | 9999-12-31     | NM2 | 2019-10-01    | 9999-12-31     |
+------------+-------+--------+------------+-----+---------------+----------------+-----+---------------+----------------+-----+---------------+----------------+
```

Actual:

```
+---------+-----------+--------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+
| GroupID | GroupName | GovtID | GroupIndicativeTermDate |      AB      |      CD      |      MM      | Name_Eff_Date | Name_Term_Date |
+---------+-----------+--------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+
|   12345 | James     |  13131 | 9999-12-31              | OHMDFP000096 | OHMDFP000096 | NULL         | 2017-10-01    | 9999-12-31     |
|   12345 | James     |  13131 | 9999-12-31              | NULL         | NULL         | OHMAFP000055 | 2019-01-01    | 9999-12-31     |
+---------+-----------+--------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Sample data will greatly help us help you. It's much easier for us to help you get from A to B, rather than from back from C to B (after you arrived at C from A)

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the sample data.

Comment: Images don't help us, I'm afraid. If you're supplying data, it needs to be text.

Comment: I attempted to copy and paste from Excel, it was accepting as an image.  Here's the data.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLfCH.png

Comment: GroupID Name GovtID GTermDate GNetID GNetPre GAgreeID Name_Eff_Date Name_Term_Date HistDate
12345 James 13131 12/31/9999 CS1 AB NM1 10/1/2017 12/31/9999 8/22/2019
12345 James 13131 12/31/9999 CS1 CD NM1 10/1/2017 12/31/9999 8/22/2019
12345 James 13131 12/31/9999 MAT1 MM NM2 1/1/2019 12/31/9999 8/22/2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Setup:

So, you've got a lot going on here.  The first advice I would give is to provide data in a way that can be easily consumed by those trying to help you:

```
create table #AllGroup (
    Name nvarchar(255),
    GroupID int,
    GovtID int,
    GTermDate date,
    GNetPre char(2),
    GAgreeID char(3),
    Name_Eff_Date date,
    Name_Term_Date date
);

insert #AllGroup values 
    ('James', 12345, 13131, '9999-12-31', 'AB', 'NM1', '2017-10-01', '9999-12-31'),
    ('James', 12345, 13131, '9999-12-31', 'CD', 'NM1', '2017-10-01', '9999-12-31'),
    ('James', 12345, 13131, '9999-12-31', 'MM', 'NM2', '2019-10-01', '9999-12-31');
```

#### Multi-Column Pivot:

Before we even get to the dynamic SQL, we should go over how to pivot on multiple columns in SQL.

This is the non-dynamic version of what you're doing:

```
select     GroupID, Name, GovtID, GTermDate, Name_Eff_Date, Name_Term_Date, AB, CD, MM
from       #allGroup ag
pivot      (max(GAgreeID) for GNetPre in (AB, CD, MM)) q
```

To do what you intend, don't use the `pivot` keyword.  Just aggregate on conditionals:

```
select       GroupID, Name, GovtID, GTermDate, 

             AB = max(iif(GNetPre = 'AB', GAgreeID, null)),
             AB_Name_Eff_Date = max(iif(GNetPre = 'AB', Name_Eff_Date, null)),
             AB_Name_Term_Date = max(iif(GNetPre = 'AB', Name_Term_Date, null)),             

             CD = max(iif(GNetPre = 'CD', GAgreeID, null)),
             CD_Name_Eff_Date = max(iif(GNetPre = 'CD', Name_Eff_Date, null)),
             CD_Name_Term_Date = max(iif(GNetPre = 'CD', Name_Term_Date, null)),            

             MM = max(iif(GNetPre = 'MM', GAgreeID, null)),
             MM_Name_Eff_Date = max(iif(GNetPre = 'MM', Name_Eff_Date, null)),
             MM_Name_Term_Date = max(iif(GNetPre = 'MM', Name_Term_Date, null))             

from         #allGroup ag
group by     GroupId, Name, GovtID, GTermDate
```

If you don't have a high enough version of SQL Server to utilize `iif`, just use `case` statements.

Note that you can do this for single column pivoting as well.  In fact, it's generally more performant, even if less elegant in terms of syntax.

#### Dynamic SQL:

Instead of @pivotCols being a string, you're going to have to make it into a table:

```
declare @pivotCols table (colName sysname, colSql varchar(max));
insert @pivotCols (colName) values ('AB'),('CD'),('MM');
```

Note that we only populated the name, not the sql.  That comes next:

```
update @pivotCols set colSql = replace(
    '
        @col = max(iif(GNetPre = ''@col'', GAgreeID, null)),
        @col_Name_Eff_Date = max(iif(GNetPre = ''@col'', Name_Eff_Date, null)),
        @col_Name_Term_Date = max(iif(GNetPre = ''@col'', Name_Term_Date, null)),', 
    '@col', 
    colName
);
```

Now loop to aggregate the colSql values into a single statement:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '';
select @sql += colSql from @pivotCols
```

And then wrap that to create the full statement:

```
set @sql = 
    'select GroupID, Name, GovtID, GTermDate, ' + 
    left(@sql, len(@sql) - 1) + -- gets rid of the final comma
    ' into ##TBL_TEMP from #AllGroup group by GroupID, Name, GovtID, GTermDate';
```

Finally, run it to get your results:

```
if object_id('tempdb..##TBL_TEMP') is not null
    drop table ##TBL_TEMP;

exec (@sql);

select * from ##TBL_TEMP;
```

Below is a result set for the code, (except before running it I had to tweak it slightly to get the dates to output the way I wanted).

[image: results]

#### Warnings:

The standard warning with dynamic sql is to worry about sql injection.  So be sure that there is no way, directly or indirectly, that an external user could manipulate @pivotCols.

Also, what you're trying to do is really only justified for reporting purposes.  It is generally best done with presentation tools such as with an SSRS Matrix or putting it through a 3-tiered architecture, or similar.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much.  I'll look at this closely to try to understand what it is doing!